# How to call a function automatically on a specific page?

Tags: flutter, dart, init

I want to fetch a random quote from an API.
This is my function:

```
static Future<String?> getRandomQuote() async {
    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {'Content-Type': 'application.json'};
    var url = Uri.https("api.quotable.io", "/random");
    var response = await client.get(url, headers: requestHeaders);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(data["content"]);
      return data["content"].toString();
    } else {
      return "Sorry. Unable to Fetch Quote for you.".toString();
    }
  }
```

From this function, I want to get the string in another file:

```
String? _quote = "hey..";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    gotQuote();
  }

  void gotQuote() async {
    this._quote = await APIservice.getRandomQuote();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
```

And, going to use this string value here,

```
        child: Center(
          child: AnimatedTextKit(
            animatedTexts: [
              TyperAnimatedText(
                _quote!,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontFamily: '',
                  wordSpacing: 2,
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

But it does not show the output there. `getRandomQuote()` function properly as if it print value in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with what you already have, you need to call setState affect fetching from the api.

```
void gotQuote() async {
   var response  = await APIservice.getRandomQuote();
   
   setState((){
      this._quote = response;
   });
}
```

But using a FutureBuilder is the best approach for handling what view to render based on the response success or failure.

Answer (score 1):

While you are using a future method, It would be better to use [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

```dart
final future = APIservice.getRandomQuote();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        FutureBuilder<String?>(
          future: future,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                  child: AnimatedTextKit(
                animatedTexts: [
                  TyperAnimatedText(
                    snapshot.data ?? "",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontFamily: '',
                      wordSpacing: 2,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ));
            }
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("Got error");
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
```

Find more about [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Thanks..It works...Can you please tell me some font family or provide a resource where list of font family listed?

Comment: You can try [google_fonts](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts) or for your case check [/design/fonts](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts)